# Are these tools appropriate for a roofing project?

Tags: repair, roof, tools, powertools, roofing

Okay so I have a 2 story house about 30 feet high and was wondering if this set up will work?

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-20-Gal-175-psi-Quiet-Portable-Air-Compressor-C201H/206189626

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Bostitch-21-Degree-Industrial-Round-Head-Framing-Nailer-F21PL/100465406

I have quiet a lot of shingles to replace and would like for the power tool to run continuously. I'm just curious if it will work since the air compressor doesn't meet the SCFM requirement for the power tool i want to use. The air hose I want to use will be a 3-8-in-x-50-ft-F5-Male-x-Male-Fittings-Hose.

Will this work? If not can anyone please recommend the air compressor and hose i will need to run this power tool continuously.

Comment: Sorry, but shopping advice is considered off-topic at DIYSE. Best of luck.

Comment: And that's a framing nailer. You don't want that for roofing.

Comment: @isherwood Well this is the first time i've done this and i wanted to know if i was doing it right. A simple yes or no would be enough

Comment: We'd like to help more with this type of thing, but 1) a simple yes or no doesn't get you very far, and 2) the value of the question to the community is minimal considering the short lifespan of links and the products they point to. It's nothing personal. Have a look at the Help pages to better understand our mission here.

Comment: Any compressor that can provide the pressure needed for the gun to operate will work. If the compressor has a low scfm you will have to wait a bit between nails. (Ok for a home owner but not a pro). I have not found a do everything gun!!! Roofing nailers are diferent than framers or finish nailers. If you want to do framing or roofing get 1 gun for each or you will spend more time clearing jams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your question: are these tools appropriate?, the answer is mostly no.

The gun you've linked is (as noted by others) a framing nailer. (It shoots long nails with relatively small heads.) You want a roofing nailer (short nails, big heads). I don't have any experience with the so-called combi tools, but in general, those sorts of things are a compromise.

The compressor is way too huge, unless you're thinking of painting your house. Maybe you're stuck on the idea of continuous cfm, which doesn't apply to nailers, but does apply to things like paint guns, sanders, or impact wrenches. Anything around 4-6 gallons will be adequate, with a bigger one offering more shots before it refills itself.

Get a 100' hose (or 2-50') and leave the compressor on the ground. (Some don't like to operate on an angle because they rely on oil lubricating the engine.) A slightly bigger hose (>1/4") will help with pressure drop.

Given the drop and potential injury, get a fall arrest kit (full body harness, rope grab, rope, anchor point) and learn what's involved in using it. Seriously. Even modestly sloped roofs have edges you can slip off.

Have your roofing materials boomed onto the roof. It costs more, but will save your back and be safer.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen nail guns that accept both roofing and framing nails; I would look for one like that. I would generally recommend a coil nailer, which holds more nails, and usually accepts roofing and framing nails (but be sure to check it before you buy it).

As for air tanks, I would look for something on the small side (like 6 gal) for roofing, because I find that you have to keep moving the tank. You also have to think about carrying or hoisting it up and down. Lighter is easier.

Comment: would it be possible to just get a really long hose and have one like the one i linked above pushing the air up to the gun?

Comment: @user3882522 Possible, yes- but practical, no. Having a portable compressor will make your roofing project go more smoothly. If you want to test this, leave the compressor on the ground (I think you discover why it's better to have it on the roof after you get started). Either way, a small compressor is really all you need for one gun. A long hose can be helpful or problematic (as gravity or coiled hoses will pull on the gun, making you unable to set the gun down). Really, hose length depends on circumstances. The only advice I have for roofing hoses is use one that doesn't weigh much.